# How can I modify CI build workflow file to run my forked repo in Maven and Java code?

Tags: maven, github, github-actions

I am trying to run this ci maven and java code to check for flakiness but I cannot access the forked branch that I created. I was able to use the same code with the original repo to clone the file and check if it was flaky or not. But, when I forked it and ran it again with the forked GitHub repo link, it failed to find any test or the location of the test. I am not sure what to change in the CI build workflow file to run my forked repo.

This is the CI workflow file I created. I added the required access to my forked repo as it didn’t have specified access before.

```
Skip to content

Search or jump to...
Pull requests
Issues
Codespaces
Marketplace
Explore
 
@krishp2 
krishp2
/
DataflowTemplates
Public
forked from GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates
Cannot fork because you own this repository and are not a member of any organizations.
Code
Pull requests
Actions
Projects
Security
Insights
Settings
flaky test 7
Update maven3.yml #20
Jobs
Run details
Workflow file for this run
.github/workflows/maven3.yml at 175023e

# This workflow will build a Java project with Maven, and cache/restore any dependencies to improve the workflow execution time
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-java-with-maven

# This workflow uses actions that are not certified by GitHub.
# They are provided by a third-party and are governed by
# separate terms of service, privacy policy, and support
# documentation.

name: flaky test 7
#is flacky
on:
  push:
     branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
     #types: [closed]
     branches: [ "main" ] 

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout 
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
     
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        cache: maven
      
    - name: Build
      run: |
         git clone https://github.com/##/DataflowTemplates.git
         cd DataflowTemplates
         mvn install -DskipTests -am -pl .
   
    - name: Create Maven settings files
      run: |
        mkdir -p $HOME/.m2
        echo "<settingsSecurity><master>###</master></settingsSecurity>" > $HOME/.m2/settings-security.xml
        echo "<settings><servers><server><id>github</id><username>###</username><password>#####</password></server></servers></settings>" > $HOME/.m2/settings.xml
        chmod 600 $HOME/.m2/settings-security.xml $HOME/.m2/settings.xml

    - name: Run test w/o Nondex
      run: |
        cd DataflowTemplates
        mvn test -pl . -Dtest=v1/src/test/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/BulkDecompressorTest.java#testDecompressUnknownCompressionFile -e -X
        
    - name: run test with Nondex
      run: |
        cd DataflowTemplates
        mvn edu.illinois:nondex-maven-plugin:2.1.1:nondex -pl . -DnondexRuns=10 -Dtest=v1/src/test/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/templates/BulkDecompressorTest.java#testDecompressUnknownCompressionFile -e -X
Update maven3.yml · krishp2/DataflowTemplates@175023e
```

The error i am getting (check the last line. Basically saying - no test files are found) -

```
[INFO] No Test Failed with this configuration.
[INFO] *********
[INFO] *********
[INFO] mvn nondex:nondex  -DnondexFilter='.*' -DnondexMode=FULL -DnondexSeed=1057510 -DnondexStart=0 -DnondexEnd=9223372036854775807 -DnondexPrintstack=false -DnondexDir="/home/runner/work/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/.nondex" -DnondexJarDir="/home/runner/work/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/.nondex" -DnondexExecid=pAdDfhtHD5Hw6clNZg6lvYUkwkxqZrqfeUrqL6gMxA= -DnondexLogging=CONFIG
[INFO] No Test Failed with this configuration.
[INFO] *********
[INFO] *********
[INFO] mvn nondex:nondex  -DnondexFilter='.*' -DnondexMode=FULL -DnondexSeed=1098954 -DnondexStart=0 -DnondexEnd=9223372036854775807 -DnondexPrintstack=false -DnondexDir="/home/runner/work/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/.nondex" -DnondexJarDir="/home/runner/work/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/.nondex" -DnondexExecid=nMrjtytlpQdLQEKM32MsiMHMoXNzpocdyduZiykz7Vk= -DnondexLogging=CONFIG
[INFO] No Test Failed with this configuration.
[INFO] *********
[INFO] *********
[INFO] mvn nondex:nondex  -DnondexFilter='.*' -DnondexMode=FULL -DnondexSeed=1140398 -DnondexStart=0 -DnondexEnd=9223372036854775807 -DnondexPrintstack=false -DnondexDir="/home/runner/work/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/.nondex" -DnondexJarDir="/home/runner/work/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/.nondex" -DnondexExecid=s8WuoF7G0gqb58OJtoSPC7xNUJ+ajyeLxzz13xC7DBs= -DnondexLogging=CONFIG
[INFO] No Test Failed with this configuration.
[INFO] *********
[INFO] *********
[INFO] mvn nondex:nondex  -DnondexFilter='.*' -DnondexMode=FULL -DnondexSeed=1181842 -DnondexStart=0 -DnondexEnd=9223372036854775807 -DnondexPrintstack=false -DnondexDir="/home/runner/work/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/.nondex" -DnondexJarDir="/home/runner/work/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/.nondex" -DnondexExecid=USsJDp06Vqb62JSJylILxFvs9JGZP0J1IuEXc+uM704= -DnondexLogging=CONFIG
[INFO] No Test Failed with this configuration.
[INFO] *********
[INFO] *********
[INFO] mvn nondex:nondex  -DnondexFilter='.*' -DnondexMode=FULL -DnondexSeed=1223286 -DnondexStart=0 -DnondexEnd=9223372036854775807 -DnondexPrintstack=false -DnondexDir="/home/runner/work/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/.nondex" -DnondexJarDir="/home/runner/work/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/.nondex" -DnondexExecid=DWhVgi9hMkXr+zS60QBFJkb6s4RjKftmZKYdbHyfPTs= -DnondexLogging=CONFIG
[INFO] No Test Failed with this configuration.
[INFO] *********
[INFO] *********
[INFO] mvn nondex:nondex  -DnondexFilter='.*' -DnondexMode=FULL -DnondexSeed=1264730 -DnondexStart=0 -DnondexEnd=9223372036854775807 -DnondexPrintstack=false -DnondexDir="/home/runner/work/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/.nondex" -DnondexJarDir="/home/runner/work/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/.nondex" -DnondexExecid=TTekVJS5nhez7cj+409vHeUk7Xuk9oh3g8mJ6zHYync= -DnondexLogging=CONFIG
[INFO] No Test Failed with this configuration.
[INFO] *********
[INFO] *********
[INFO] mvn nondex:nondex  -DnondexFilter='.*' -DnondexMode=FULL -DnondexSeed=1306174 -DnondexStart=0 -DnondexEnd=9223372036854775807 -DnondexPrintstack=false -DnondexDir="/home/runner/work/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/.nondex" -DnondexJarDir="/home/runner/work/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/.nondex" -DnondexExecid=T7htMYD3cEydyiMvVkP+E0PJ+gK6daFss4VzipcvQ= -DnondexLogging=CONFIG
[INFO] No Test Failed with this configuration.
[INFO] *********
[INFO] All tests pass without NonDex shuffling
[INFO] ####################
[INFO] Across all seeds:
[INFO] Test results can be found at: 
[INFO] file:///home/runner/work/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/DataflowTemplates/.nondex/GoJC1ppP9UaGpQULgp3yFWWWU6eDvaIisx+CCbPl7iI=/test_results.html
[INFO] [NonDex] The id of this run is: GoJC1ppP9UaGpQULgp3yFWWWU6eDvaIisx+CCbPl7iI=
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.135 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-21T02:28:15Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error:  Failed to execute goal edu.illinois:nondex-maven-plugin:2.1.1:nondex (default-cli) on project templates: Unable to execute mojo: No tests were executed!  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]
```

I am very certian that it has to do something with the location that i provide. But i have no clue on how to change it for the forked file. Additionaly, below i am attaching the code for the CI file that worked for me in the original repo(With no changes)

```
# This workflow will build a Java project with Maven, and cache/restore any dependencies to improve the workflow execution time
# For more information see: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/automating-builds-and-tests/building-and-testing-java-with-maven

# This workflow uses actions that are not certified by GitHub.
# They are provided by a third-party and are governed by
# separate terms of service, privacy policy, and support
# documentation.

name: flaky test 7
#is flacky
on:
  push:
     branches: [ "main" ]
  pull_request:
     #types: [closed]
     branches: [ "main" ] 

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Checkout 
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      
    - name: Set up JDK 11
      uses: actions/setup-java@v2
     
      with:
        java-version: '11'
        distribution: 'temurin'
        cache: maven
      
    - name: Build
      run: |
         git clone https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates
         cd DataflowTemplates
         mvn clean
         git checkout 5094c7b39de511c9ed441d9fde28553a88f68e4b
         mvn install -DskipTests -am -pl .
     
    - name: Run test w/o Nondex
      run: |
        cd DataflowTemplates
        mvn test -pl . -Dtest=com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.BulkDecompressorTest#testDecompressUnknownCompressionFile
        
    - name: run test with Nondex
      run: |
        cd DataflowTemplates
        mvn edu.illinois:nondex-maven-plugin:2.1.1:nondex -pl . -DnondexRuns=10 -Dtest=com.google.cloud.teleport.templates.BulkDecompressorTest#testDecompressUnknownCompressionFile
```

This worked for me on the original repo. PLease help me if you know how to work on forked files in worklow. Thanks!